# How to handle Mouseover in Selenium 2 API

Tags: selenium, mouseover

```
String strPrimaryNav = "MEN";
String strSecondaryNav = "Shoes";
String strTertiaryNav = "Golf";

driver.findElement(By.linkText(strPrimaryNav)).click();

WebElement weSecNav = driver.findElement(By.className("secondaryButton").linkText(strSecondaryNav));

Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseDown(((Locatable)weSecNav).getCoordinates());
//just trying with for loop as the tertiary popup disappears quickly and hence getting ElementNotVisible Exception
for (int i = 0 ; i< 2; i++){
    mouse.mouseDown(((Locatable)weSecNav).getCoordinates());
    //mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)weSecNav).getCoordinates(), 0, 0 );
    //WebElement weTerNav = driver.findElement(By.className("tertiaryButton").linkText(strTertiaryNav));
    WebElement weTerNav = driver.findElement(By.linkText(strTertiaryNav));
    boolean isSecDisplayed = ((RenderedWebElement)weTerNav).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("isDisplayed: " + isSecDisplayed);
    System.out.println(" " + ((RenderedWebElement)weSecNav).getAttribute("href"));
    System.out.println(" " + ((RenderedWebElement)weSecNav).getValueOfCssProperty("action"));
    weTerNav.click();
}
```

I was trying the below code using selenium 2 but, the tertiary popup not stays long to click it and hence getting ElementNotVisible exception at Tertiary click.

Comment: How long is the element supposed to be visible? I guess what I'm getting at is, why is Seleinum not clicking it in time? What is delaying Selenium from clicking it? In my experience, that happens really fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least check that the element is visible before you send your click:

```
Selenium s = new WebDriverBackedSelenium( driver, URL );
s.waitForCondition( "!( document.getElementById('.....') === null )", "20000" );
s.click( .... );
```

This avoids the exception. I'm not sure there is a way to make the popup stay any longer than it should.